# How to scan Qr-code in angular 2 application?

Tags: angular, qr-code, angular-cli

I am trying to create an application where it will scan a qr-code with angular-cli?
I did found few npm modules like qrcode-reader. But any of them are working with angular 2. I guess, beacuse qrcode-reader more like nodejs server side module.
Is there anyway to build the application?

Answer (score 2):

Once I used [@zxing/ngx-scanner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zxing/ngx-scanner)  and it worked fine.
See demo [here](https://zxing-js.github.io/ngx-scanner/).

easy to use:

```
<!-- some.component.html -->
<zxing-scanner></zxing-scanner>
```

Install: `npm i @zxing/ngx-scanner`

Comment: Doesn't support angular <5 apps :(

Answer (score 0):

I am using barcodeScanner in ng-cordova to scan barcodes.  I had to make code changes in ngCordova to make it work correctly with the barcodeScanner plugin (there are several versions of it out there), but it's working great now.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed angular2-qrscanner in a project and it seems to be working right out of the box. (it's only for Chrome, FF, and Opera though)

Github: https://github.com/tulkasEldarion/angular2-qrscanner

install: `npm install angular2-qrscanner --save`

use: `<qr-scanner (onRead)="callback($event)"></qr-scanner>`

Comment: Can you tell me how can you do that

Comment: Works great for development but plugin doesn't work with aot as of v0.1.11 - https://github.com/goergch/angular2-qrscanner/issues/29

Comment: (onRead) property is not working, its not calling the function callback(). Can you please help me